# Issues Mirroring Weight Paint

Tags: modifiers, bones, weight-painting, mirror

I have setup R and L labled bones and am trying to copy all of the weight gradients of the bones labled L, to the similar named bones labled R on the symmetrical model. 
The model is resting in the center of the scene, and all R labled bones have been exactly mirrored across the x-axis as well as being rotated normally to "view axis".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So what issue are you having?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need empty vertex groups for the right side, which you can automatically create when you parent the model to the armature. Also make sure you are using a mirror modifier and it has the vertex groups option turned on.

Comment: Clear, like delete all of the R vertex groups? (I'm almost a complete beginner so sorry if I sound dumb with this program.)

Comment: No no, you need the R vertex groups - they should exist, but do not contain any manual weights unless you want them to influence the left side, too.

Comment: I ran into this problem recently, too. A simple fix was to parent the mesh to the armature again, and doing so with "Empty Groups". This will create properly named .L/.R vertex groups that will hold the weights that the mirror modifier will put in them.